# jquery.fullBg plugin mixed with jquery.flash.js plugin: movie disappear when wmode=transparent

Tags: jquery, flash, transparent, wmode

Im the new kid on the block so I apologyze if I'm not doing very well.
I'm using together the full image background plugin:
http://bavotasan.com/2011/full-sizebackground-image-jquery-plugin/
And the flash loader background plugin:
http://jquery.lukelutman.com/plugins/flash/

Everything works fine till the moment in which I set the wmode param of the flash movie to transparent, then the movie completely disappears (it loads, as I can listen at the sounds) but it doesn't show.

I would like to have a full background image with the transparent flash movie over it, that's all, if somebody can tell me how to fix this or even a new way to do it, it will be so good!!

Here is my code, so simple, by the way:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#background").fullBg();
$('#flashcontent').flash(
    { src: '../movie.swf',
      width: 934,
      height: 591,
      wmode:'transparent',
      access:'domain',
      express:'express_install.swf',
      classid:'clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000',
      codebase:'http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=',
      plugin:'http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer',
      mime:'application/x-shockwave-flash',
      version:'8.0',
    }
);)};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transparent means see-through, Which is exactly what's happening, It becomes see-through, so you see the background and hear the sounds.

If you want certain parts of it to be transparent, then as far as I know, you can do that in Flash itself when you're making the movie.